# Style an array of elements that have a specific computed css property value

Tags: javascript

**What I want to achieve:**
All children with an opacity of 0.01 get an increment of 1 in their opacity values.

**Problem:** As you can see below, this is as far as I got. I cant figure out how to tell js to select all those children elements based on a computed value and add some style to them. I looped through them and got their indexes, as well as their computed values but that is where im stuck now.

**HTML:**

```
 <div id='a'>
    <span>How</span>
    <span>are</span>
    <span>you?</span>
 </div>
```

**JS:**

```
var elem = document.getElementById('a');
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var x = window.getComputedStyle(elem.children[i], null).getPropertyValue('opacity');
    parseFloat(x)[i]
}
```

**Question:** How do I add some style to an array of elements that have a specific computed value of a property?

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: Possibly due to no reproducible code/html

Comment: @mplungjan I know but that person could have told me. Its was pretty rude. Ok I will add some more code

Comment: @mplungjan excuse me but is this fine now?

Comment: I guess you could add some styling so the code will actually do something. I am off to bed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to capture the return value `parseFloat()` if you want to do anything with it. You'll want to do something like this:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('a');
for (i = 0; i < elem.children.length; i++) {
    var x = window.getComputedStyle(elem.children[i], null).getPropertyValue('opacity');
    var opacity = parseFloat(x);
    if (opacity === 1.0) {
       elem.children[i].style.your_style = whatever;
    }
}
```

Comment: and also change `10` to `elem.children.length` otherwise it raise error if children count less than 10 :-)

Comment: @Grundy Thanks! For some reason I didn't bother to check that line.